# Excel VBA Loop Through Part of The Sheets by List of Names

Tags: vba, excel

I Have List of Names of Companies in a table and I need, by this list in the Data sheet, to go the sheet with the company Name and copy data to the table. I built a code that does it 15 times for each comapny and I will be greatful to whom can find me a certain loop that will search through the specific sheets and copy the data that I need.

here is a sample of 2 of the 15 codes to each sheet:

```
Sheets("Comapny1").Activate
Range("H2").End(xlDown).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Copy
Sheets("Data").Activate
Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Find("Comapny1").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

Sheets("Comapny2").Activate
Range("H2").End(xlDown).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Copy
Sheets("Data").Activate
Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Find("Comapny2").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Comment: I'd advise to not using `Select`. Do you need any of the formatting when you're copying? If not, then use `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").value`

Comment: I didn't understood your solution

Comment: it is not a solution. it is a tip on writing better code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option explicit

Sub LoopThroughCompanies()

    Dim Company as Range
    Dim Companies as Range

    Set Companies = Thisworkbook.Worksheets(NameOfSheetWithCompaniesOnIt).range(TableName[ColumnName])

    For each Company in Companies
        With thisworbook.worksheets(company.value2)
            .activate
            .Range("H2").End(xlDown).Select
            .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Copy
        End with
        With thisworkbook.workSheets("Data")
            .Activate
            .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Find(company.value2,,xlvalues,xlwhole,).Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        End with
    Next Company

End sub
```

Untested and written on mobile, sorry for bad formatting. You should not use activate/select, but I did not want to edit your original code too much, if you know that it's working.

Replace NameOfSheetWithCompaniesOnIt with actual name, as per your workbook.

Replace TableName[ColumnName] with actual table name and column name, as per your workbook.

Hope it works.

Comment: it stops with an error in line: , `.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Find(company.value2,,xlvalues,xlwhole,).Activate` I changed that line to companies instead of range to Companies and it still not works

Comment: Excellent, you're welcome, though I'm sorry it did not work as is. Maybe I (wrongly) assumed too much about the layout of your sheets or something.

Answer (score 1):

Try this after changing the sheetname and the range where you have list of companies,

```
Sub test()

    Dim companies As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set companies = Sheets("CompnayNamesSheet").Range("A1:A10")

    For Each cell In companies

        Sheets(cell.Value).Activate
        Range("H2").End(xlDown).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Copy

        Sheets("Data").Activate
        Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Find(cell.Value).Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: You should avoid using `.Select`

Comment: Absolutely ! The solution that I have posted is just for looping through the sheet names the other code is untouched.

Comment: it stops with an error in line sheets (cell).Activate